# Is it possible to monitor incoming calls on a connected iPhone and send automated responses via a Mac app?

Tags: ios, swift, macos-ventura, osascript, facetime

I need to include in my app a way to monitor whenever an incoming call takes place, which won't be answered by anyone; and then send a customized automated response to the caller using Messages app.
The app runs on the Mac and every user has their iPhone connected to the Mac so whenever a call enters, it will also be caught in the Mac.

As an alternative it is useful for me if I can only check the list of missed calls from time to time as long as I have the caller ID.

My question: is this something feasible?

So far what I have read is that it isn't, due to the fact that there is no API from Apple to allow it on the Mac nor on the iPhone. I would rather do it on my current Mac app but I'll settle for iOS if nothing else is possible.

Do you guys have any insights on the topic?

I started out by reading documentation and blog posts about the topic but everything was suggesting me that it can't be done.

PS. It's an in-house app and it will only deal with callers from Contacts

Comment: You could build a VoIP service that does this, like [Grasshopper](https://grasshopper.com), but hooking in via a regular app to someone's iPhone calls is not going to happen. It would have to be a separate number in a separate app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to include in my app a way to monitor whenever an incoming call takes place,

This is impossible, unless these are calls to a VoIP app you control. You cannot access voice calls from your app.

> So far what I have read is that it isn't, due to the fact that there is no API from Apple to allow it on the Mac nor on the iPhone.

Exactly as you say. It's not possible, by design, even for an enterprise app. There is no API for it unless you're going to jailbreak all the phones (I don't know the API that exists in that case, but it might be possible).